# Access nodeport via kube-proxy from another machine

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

I have kubernetes cluster (node01-03). 
There is a service with nodeport to access a pod (nodeport 31000). 
The pod is running on node03. 
I can access the service with http://node03:31000 from any host. On every node I can access the service like http://[name_of_the_node]:31000. But I cannot access the service the following way: http://node01:31000 even though there is a listener (kube-proxy) on node01 at port 31000. The iptables rules look okay to me. Is this how it's intended to work ? If not, how can I further troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NodePort` is exposed on **every** node in the cluster. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport clearly says:

> each Node will proxy that port (the same port number on every Node) into your Service

So, from both inside and outside the cluster, the service can be accessed using `NodeIP:NodePort` on **any** node in the cluster and kube-proxy will route using iptables to the right node that has the backend pod.

However, if the service is accessed using `NodeIP:NodePort` from outside the cluster, we need to first make sure that `NodeIP` is reachable from where we are hitting `NodeIP:NodePort`.

If `NodeIP:NodePort` cannot be accessed on a node that is **not** running the backend pod, it may be caused by the default `DROP` rule on the `FORWARD` chain (which in turn is caused by Docker `1.13` for security reasons). [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40182#issuecomment-276392353) is more info about it. Also see step **8** [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/). A solution for this is to add the following rule on the node:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
```

The k8s issue for this is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/39823) and the fix is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/52569) (the fix should be there in k8s 1.9).

Three other options to enable external access to a service are:

1. `ExternalIPs`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips
2. `LoadBalancer` with an external, cloud-provider's load-balancer: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-loadbalancer
3. `Ingress`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: I can reach all nodes, but i cannot connect to [node_ip_where_the _pod_is_not_running]:[nodeport]

Comment: @m0087 is `kube-proxy` running? It should redirect the request to the right backend pod - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-iptables

Comment: Yes, and It's working if I am on a node and use the name of the node. E.g. I'm on node01 (the pod runs on node03) and access http://node01:[nodeport].

Comment: @m0087 I think you are seeing `iptables` issue in docker. Can you try `iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT` on the node and check? I've edited my answer with the required info. Please see the section "If `NodeIP:NodePort` cannot be accessed on a node that is **not** running the backend pod" in my answer above.

Comment: @m0087 Glad to help. Upvote my answer if you think it is useful so that others know this is the right answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If accessing pods within the Kubernetes cluster, you dont need to use the nodeport.  Infer the Kubernetes service targetport instead.  Say podA needs to access podB through service called serviceB.  All you need assuming http is http://serviceB:targetPort/

Comment: Good to know. I didnt knew that. But I want to know: do I always have to check on which node a pod is running in order to access a service from external?

Comment: You do not have to.  K8s will automatically add to iptables the ip addresses of pods.  K8s dns will handle resolving service names to actual IPs of pods.  All you need to make sure is that kube-dns is running on each node.